# Problem using CSV to query a website, input isn't right

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am fairly new at python programming but have a column of terms I want to search a website for. The code is as follows:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

col_list = ['Molecular Formula'] #this is a column title in my csv file
Chem = pd.read_csv('single.csv', usecols=col_list)
res = requests.get('https://hmdb.ca/unearth/q?utf8=✓&query='+ Chem +'&searcher=metabolites&button=')
html_page = res.content
soup = BS(html_page, 'html.parser')
body = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'hit-name'})

for div in body:
    print(div.text)
```

I want to use the column information to fill in for the "Chem" term in the search. If I just use Chem = "some specific chemical" it works great. As it is written I get the following error - No connection adapters were found for 'Molecular Formula\n0  [https://hmdb.ca/unearth/q?utf8=✓&query=C10H7NO...\n1](https://hmdb.ca/unearth/q?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=C10H7NO...%5Cn1)  [https://hmdb.ca/unearth/q?utf8=✓&query=C11N12O...'](https://hmdb.ca/unearth/q?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=C11N12O...%27). Maybe this has to do with the numbers that pandas adds to each row? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use for-loop to iterate over the values in "Molecular Formula" column. For example:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

col_list = ["Molecular Formula"]  # this is a column title in my csv file
Chem = pd.read_csv("data.csv", usecols=col_list)

for c in Chem["Molecular Formula"]:
    res = requests.get(
        "https://hmdb.ca/unearth/q?utf8=✓&query="
        + c
        + "&searcher=metabolites&button="
    )
    html_page = res.content
    soup = BS(html_page, "html.parser")
    body = soup.find_all("div", attrs={"class": "hit-name"})

    for div in body:
        print(div.text)
    print("-" * 80)
```

Prints:

```
Succinylcholine
2-Ethyl-4,5-dimethylthiazole
Water
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Licoricesaponin C2
Illudin C2
Eremopetasitenin C2
Cinncassiol C2
Gladiatoside C2
Prostaglandin-c2
Capsicoside C2
Schidigerasaponin C2
Ganoderic acid C2
Ginsenoside C
Diethyl sulfide
Mangiferin
4-Nitrophenol
L-Acetylcarnitine
Malonic acid
11-trans-Leukotriene C4
(-)-Epigallocatechin
Tryptophan 2-C-mannoside
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

contents of `data.csv`:

```
Molecular Formula
H2O
C2
```

---

EDIT: To save results to CSV:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

col_list = ["Molecular Formula"]  # this is a column title in my csv file
Chem = pd.read_csv("data.csv", usecols=col_list)

all_data = []
for c in Chem["Molecular Formula"]:
    print(f"Getting {c=}")
    res = requests.get(
        "https://hmdb.ca/unearth/q?utf8=✓&query="
        + c
        + "&searcher=metabolites&button="
    )
    html_page = res.content
    soup = BS(html_page, "html.parser")
    body = soup.find_all("div", attrs={"class": "hit-name"})

    for div in body:
        all_data.append([c, div.text])

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data, columns=["Molecular Formula", "Value"])
print(df)
df.to_csv("result.csv", index=False)
```

Prints:

```
Getting c='H2O'
Getting c='C2'
   Molecular Formula                         Value
0                H2O               Succinylcholine
1                H2O  2-Ethyl-4,5-dimethylthiazole
2                H2O                         Water
3                 C2            Licoricesaponin C2
4                 C2                    Illudin C2
5                 C2           Eremopetasitenin C2
6                 C2                Cinncassiol C2
7                 C2               Gladiatoside C2
8                 C2              Prostaglandin-c2
9                 C2                Capsicoside C2
10                C2          Schidigerasaponin C2
11                C2             Ganoderic acid C2
12                C2                 Ginsenoside C
13                C2               Diethyl sulfide
14                C2                    Mangiferin
15                C2                 4-Nitrophenol
16                C2             L-Acetylcarnitine
17                C2                  Malonic acid
18                C2       11-trans-Leukotriene C4
19                C2          (-)-Epigallocatechin
20                C2      Tryptophan 2-C-mannoside
```

and saves `result.csv`

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much for that it works like a dream! It may be reaching but any advice on putting that print output into a new csv?

Comment: thanks so much! I have been working on this for days. I probably need to search this data on a different site based on the results gathered into the new csv (I need to cross-reference my results), can the csv be written in rows so that H2O gives three values across the csv instead of repeating H2O three times and having a column next to it that matches it? If it is too difficult dont worry about it what you have done has already saved so much time and I can work with it.

Comment: @CharlieP If I understand you correctly, you probably want `df.groupby("Molecular Formula", as_index=False).agg(", ".join)` (this will group the dataframe by "Molecular Formula" and joins the "Value" by `,`

Comment: Thanks again for spending so much time on this.

Comment: @CharlieP If this answer resolved your problem, then please consider [accepting it as the answer to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), by clicking the checkmark to the left this will let others know this answer has been resolved. (See [What does it mean to accept an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for information)

Comment: @AndrejKesely related to this code is there a way to collect soup.find_all("div", attrs={"class": "hit-name"}) + "a", attrs={"class":"btn-card"}?

Comment: @CharlieP To not clutter the comment section I'd suggest to open a new question here on StackOverflow. I'll try to look at it.